# Include second when datediff

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

when I run query below it gives 15 minutes so doesn't include second in calculation, how to make it uncluding seconds:

```
 select datediff(minute, '2016-05-19 18:53:59.0005187','2016-05-19 19:08:00.0005035') from CPEvents1_2
```

thanks,
S

Comment: can you add the expected result. If you just need the time difference is seconds then use `Second` instead of `minute`

Comment: it should be 14 min when include seconds, because '18:53:59.0005187' is almost '18:54' so should be 14 minute.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Second` instead of `minute` in `datepart` and divide the result by `60` to get the difference in `minutes`

Try this way..

```
select datediff(SECOND, '2016-05-19 18:53:59.0005187','2016-05-19 19:08:00.0005035') / 60
```

Comment: This will tend to under-report values, in the same way as the plain `DATEDIFF` will over-report. If you want a "human intuition" type of result, probably add 30 before performing the division so that 14 minutes and 5 seconds -> 14 minutes and 14 minutes and 55 seconds -> 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can typecast to smalldatetime

```
select datediff(minute, convert(smalldatetime,'2016-05-19 18:53:59.000'),convert(smalldatetime,'2016-05-19 19:08:00.000'))
```